mruby でコンパイル時、expected String/Cptr (TypeError) のエラーが発生　対処法がわかりません
実行環境:
Ubuntu 22.04
mruby 3.3.0
https://github.com/take-cheeze/mruby-glfw3 の mrbgems をインストール
mruby/bin/mruby examples/triangle.rb を実行時、以下のエラーメッセージ
trace (most recent call last):
    [1] examples/triangle.rb:104
examples/triangle.rb:104:in glVertexAttribPointer: expected String/Cptr (TypeError)

エラーとなったソースコードは
glVertexAttribPointer pos_idx, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, nil

第6パラメータ nil がタイプエラーになったと思われます。
https://github.com/xxuejie/mruby-gles の src/mrb_gl2.c
static mrb_value
mrb_gl_vertex_attrib_pointer(mrb_state* mrb, mrb_value mod)
{
  mrb_int indx, size, type, stride;
  mrb_value normalized, ptr;

  mrb_get_args(mrb, "iiioio", &indx, &size, &type, &normalized,
               &stride, &ptr);
  GLvoid const *p;
  switch (mrb_type(ptr)) {
  case MRB_TT_STRING:
    p = RSTRING_PTR(ptr);
    break;
  case MRB_TT_CPTR:
    p = mrb_cptr(ptr);
    break;
  default:
    mrb_raise(mrb, E_TYPE_ERROR, "expected String/Cptr");
    break;
  }
  glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint) indx, (GLint) size, (GLenum) type,
                        MRB_VALUE_TO_GL_BOOLEAN(normalized),
                        (GLsizei) stride, p);

  return mrb_nil_value();
}

